# Logging Python Errors, warnings, etc

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I have been trying to write a program that will basically save all available information about the running of my program to a text file as it is being run in a batch environment where I can't see what errors/warnings/info are being generated. I have been banging my head against the wall for hours on this. I have been referring to this primarily: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file
along with some stack overflow questions but nothing seems to solve my issue.

Below is what I have.

```
import logging

for handler in logging.root.handlers[:]:
    logging.root.removeHandler(handler)

logging.basicConfig(filename = "directory/logs.txt", level = logging.DEBUG, force = True)

import pandas as pd
#import other packages used in full program

#Code with error to test capture
pprint("test")
```

When I do this, it creates the file but does not capture anything about the error. What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to log via the logging functions e.g. `logging.info("message")` (or `warn()`, `error()` etc).

Comment: Can you expand on this? Does that need to go in a specific place in the code?

Comment: Wherever you want a message logged, you insert this. Think of these methods as a 'print to the log file'. All functions with a level above the default `level` set in the `basicConfig` will be logged when the code runs.

Comment: So for example in the code above, if I want to catch the error generated by misspelling "print("test")", I put logging.info("message") after that bit of code and it will capture it? Does it need to be placed after each block of code?

Comment: No - `logging` is really just a more complex alternative to using `print` statements. You would still need to deal with the error (e.g. with a `try/except`) and then add a logging line where you wanted to record the error with whatever message was appropriate.

Comment: Ok well what I'm asking is how to capture the error generated by the code above and write it to file, apparently I'm off on how to do it, but hopefully this can clarify what I'm asking I guess.

Comment: Why are you moving all the root handlers?  Don't do that.  The list will be empty if logging is not configured yet.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about how to log _unhandled_ exceptions.  There's a recipe for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46310034/674039)

Comment: What you describe is exactly what I'm trying to do, not sure I totally understand the linked answer yet but I'll keep testing it.

Comment: @user2355903 That's is not in the linked answer, but in the question. The answer is just about how to correctly test such a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

To log an error you need to use one of the `logging` methods at an appropriate level. For example:

```
import logging

for handler in logging.root.handlers[:]:
    logging.root.removeHandler(handler)

logging.basicConfig(filename = "directory/logs.txt", level = logging.DEBUG, force = True)

import pandas as pd
#import other packages used in full program

logging.info("Starting Program...")

#Code with error to test capture
try:
    pprint("test")
except NameError as err:
    logging.error("There was an error %s", err)

logging.info("Program finished!")
```

By changing the default level in `basicConfig` you can choose which messages are included. The level order is DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR - earlier levels include later ones. So a log level of `INFO` will log all `info()`, `warn()`, and `error()` messages, but a log level of `ERROR` will only log `error()` messages.

Comment: I assume there's a parentheses missing at your first logging.info? Even so, this produces the same results for me, creates file but writes nothing to it.

Comment: This code works for me and logs all 3 lines...  If you remove `filename=` from `basicConfig` do you see the lines on the console?